# Re-tagging xetex as xelatex

Tags: support, tagging

I cannot seem to re-tag the tag `xetex` as `xelatex` even though I was able to add a tag on another question. How come?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `xelatex` is a synonym for `xetex`:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/xetex/synonyms

You should search the posts here on meta for the exact reason for this synonym being made.  In this case, it is most likely because having the two tags separate wouldn't actually be reflected in the usage: a newcomer to the site wanting to ask about something to do with `xetex`/`xelatex` probably wouldn't realise the distinction.  Moreover, there are probably very few people who would like to, say, make `xetex` one of their favourite tags whilst ignoring `xelatex`.

Comment: Heh, I just happened to be one of those few. I was wondering why TE seemed to freak out because of that. Why jump to these conclusions in the first place is beyond me. Why won't we just ditch plain, context, etc. and just assume everyone is using latex, eh?

Comment: @morbugs: It's worth reading the discussion on these matters.  Things like that were discussed at considerable length, and whilst we have no desire to be seen as laying down the law for all time, we try to act in good faith and to the benefit of all users of the site.  To a certain extent, the "latex assumption" is there because if someone _doesn't_ say then the probability is that they are a LaTeX user.  So we have to balance that reality against the desire to be engine-agnostic.  If you have any comments or suggestions, please do contribute to the relevant discussions.

Comment: Some links: [“Folding tags about various Tex engines”](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631/folding-tags-about-various-tex-engines), [“Our set of tags”](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302/our-set-of-tags/303#303) and [“What to do with the 'latex' tag?”](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365/what-to-do-with-the-latex-tag). There was also some discussion about the LaTeX tag in other questions, but I think those were the main threads.

Comment: Thanks for the links @Caramdir, and Andrew for explaining the rationale behind the decision. I didn't mean to sound so snarky; I always forget the comment-box is an `input` rather than `textarea` (pressing enter sends the comment...)

Comment: @morbusg: My snarkometer barely flickered.  One thing I dislike about using SE software for meta is that it makes it hard for newcomers to read old discussions and find out why we do some things the way that we do.  @Caramdir: thanks for the links.